# Passar variáveis com mesmo name para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Não consigo pegar o retorno dos campo no PHP, quando insiro mais que 01 em quantidade....alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
$(function() {

    var input = $('<input name="cp1" id="cp1" type="text" />');
    var input2 = $('<input name="cp2" id="cp2" type="text" />');
    var newFields = $(''); var newFields2 = $('');

    $('#qty').bind('blur keyup change', function() {
        var n = this.value || 0;
        if (n+1) {
            if (n > newFields.length) {
                addFields(n); } else {
                removeFields(n);
            }
          if (n > newFields2.length) {
                addFields(n); } else {
                removeFields(n);
            }
        }
    });

    function addFields(n) {
        for (i = newFields.length; i < n; i++) {
            var newInput = input.clone();
            newFields = newFields.add(newInput);
            newInput.appendTo('#newFields');
        }
        for (i = newFields2.length; i < n; i++) {
            var newInput2 = input2.clone();
            newFields2 = newFields2.add(newInput2);
            newInput2.appendTo('#newFields2');
        }
    }

    function removeFields(n) {
        var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
        newFields = newFields.not(removeField);

        var removeField = newFields2.slice(n).remove();
        newFields2 = newFields2.not(removeField);
    }
});
```

```css
#newFields input {
    display:block;
}
#newFields2 input {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
         <td><label>Quantidade</label></td><td><input type="number" min="0" max="10" id="qty" name="qty" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td><label>Campo01</label></td><td><label>Campo02</label></td></tr>
         <tr><td><div id="newFields"></div></td><td><div id="newFields2"></div></td></tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para pegar todos valores de alguns inputs que tem o mesmo nome é preciso adicionar colchetes no atributo `name`, dessa forma quando chegar esse campo virá como um array.

Para corrigir, adicione os colchetes na hora de multiplicar os campos:

```
$(function() {

    var input = $('<input name="cp1[]" id="cp1" type="text" />');
    var input2 = $('<input name="cp2[]" id="cp2" type="text" />');
//... demais código
```

Para verificar se os valores estão corretos pode usar a função [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), no código principal não esquece de fazer uma  validação se o array está preenchido e faça um foreach.

```
if(count($_POST['cp1']) > 0){
  foreach($_POST['cp1'] as $item){
   echo 'Itens selecionado: '. $item .'<br>';
 }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado rray, era isso mesmo! Funcionou perfeitamente!