# Armazenar múltiplos checkbox numa coluna só com PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

Estou com dificuldade em armazenar múltiplos `checkbox` em um mesmo campo da tabela. Neste caso, ao preencher o formulário e marcar mais de um `checkbox`, ele armazena somente o valor do último `checkbox`.

Seguem alguns trechos do código relacionado aos `checkbox`:

Código `PHP`:

```
$form['genero'] =  $_POST['genero'];
elseif (isset($form['genero']))
$r1 = implode(",", $form['genero']);  //<<<< Não funcionou
```

Código `PHP` para escrever os `checkbox` na tela:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="campo11">Selecione o Gênero</label><br>
                <?php 
                    foreach ($generos as $categ) {
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="'. $categ['id'].'">'. $categ['genero'] .'</input><br>'; 
                } ?>
            <br>
            </div>
```

Os `checkbox` são gerados por uma tabela que contém o ID e Nome(tabela gêneros).

Segue código PHP completo.

```
    <?php 

    $generos    =   DBRead('generos', 'ORDER BY genero DESC');

    if( !$generos)
        echo '<h2>Você não possui generos cadastradas, <a href="add-categ.php">clique aqui para resolver isto</a>!</h2>';
    else {

        if(isset($_POST['publicar'])){
            $form['tipo']       = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['tipo']) ) );
            $form['titulo']     = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['titulo']) ) );
            //$form['genero']       = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['genero']) ) );                
            $form['qualidade']  = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['qualidade']) ) );
            $form['imdb']       = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['imdb']) ) );
            $form['lancamento']     = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['lancamento']) ) );
            $form['direcao']    = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['direcao']) ) );
            $form['elenco'] = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['elenco']) ) );
            $form['conteudo']   = str_replace( '\r\n', "\n", DBEscape( trim( $_POST['conteudo']) ) );

            $form['url1']       = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['url1']) ) );              
            $form['genero'] = $_POST['genero'];
            $form['status']     = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['status']) ) );
            $form['data']       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


            if (empty( $form ['tipo'] ))
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o tipo.</div>';
            elseif  (empty( $form ['titulo'] ))
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o titulo.</div>';
            //elseif (empty( $form ['genero']))
            //  echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o gênero.</div>';
            elseif (empty( $form ['qualidade']))
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o Qualidade.</div>';
            elseif (empty( $form ['imdb']))
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o IMDB.</div>';
            elseif (empty( $form ['lancamento']))
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o Lançamento.</div>';
             elseif (empty( $form ['direcao']))
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha a Direção.</div>';
             elseif (empty( $form ['elenco']))
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o Elenco.</div>';
             elseif (empty( $form ['conteudo'])) 
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o conteudo.</div>';

            //elseif (empty( $form ['capa'])) 
                //echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o capa do filme.</div>';

            elseif (empty( $form ['url1'])) 
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o URL 1.</div>';

             elseif (empty($form['genero']))
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o campo categoria.</div>';

             elseif (empty( $form ['status']) && $form['status'] != '0') 
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o status.</div>';
             else {
                $dbCheck = DBRead('posts', "WHERE titulo ='". $form['titulo'] . "'"); /*Checa se já existe algum titulo igual no banco*/
                if($dbCheck)
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Já existe uma postagem com este titulo.</div>';
                else {
                    if( DBCreate('posts', $form ) )
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Sua postagem foi enviada com sucesso.</div>';
                    else {
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Desculpe ocorreu um erro</div>';
                    }
                }
             }



            echo '<hr>';
        }

?>
```

**Removi todos os elseif validação do formulario, para trabalhar somente com os checkboxes...**

```
    <?php 

    $generos    =   DBRead('generos', 'ORDER BY genero DESC');

    if( !$generos)
        echo '<h2>Você não possui generos cadastradas, <a href="add-categ.php">clique aqui para resolver isto</a>!</h2>';
    else {

        if(isset($_POST['publicar'])){
            $form['tipo']       = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['tipo']) ) );
            $form['titulo']     = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['titulo']) ) );
            //$form['genero']       = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['genero']) ) );                
            $form['qualidade']  = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['qualidade']) ) );
            $form['imdb']       = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['imdb']) ) );
            $form['lancamento']     = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['lancamento']) ) );
            $form['direcao']    = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['direcao']) ) );
            $form['elenco'] = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['elenco']) ) );
            $form['conteudo']   = str_replace( '\r\n', "\n", DBEscape( trim( $_POST['conteudo']) ) );
            $form['url1']       = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['url1']) ) );              
            $form['status']     = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_POST['status']) ) );
            $form['data']       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $r1 = "";
                $valor = "";
                $camposSelecionados= "";
                $form = array();
                if (isset($_POST['genero'])){
                $form =  $_POST['genero'];

                    foreach($form as $valor){
                        if (!empty($valor)){
                            $camposSelecionados .= ",$valor";
                        }
                    }

                 $r1 = implode(",", $form);
                }

                echo "Selecionados: $camposSelecionados<br>";
                echo "Todos os checkbox: $r1"; 


                    if( DBCreate('posts', $form ) )
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Sua postagem foi enviada com sucesso.</div>';
                    else {
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Desculpe ocorreu um erro</div>';
                    }
                }

            echo '<hr>';
?>
```

Agora o possuo uma mensagem de erro: 
Selecionados: ,1,2
Todos os checkbox: 1,2You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1 ) VALUES ( '1', '2' )' at line 1

Comment: vc precisa adicionar colchetes `[]` no atributo `name` para transforma isso em um array, igual [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72752/91)

Comment: Fiz isso, porém ele persiste em gravar somente o ultimo valor.

Comment: Quando vc da um `print_r($_POST['genero']);` ele vem como?

Comment: No inicio do arquivo em que vc recebe os dados do form.

Comment: Opa! consegui... Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) 
Obrigado ;)

Comment: @HenriqueSilva, esse monte de `elseif, else, if...`, eu sugiro refatorar melhor esse seu código, pois está bem bagunçado isso.

Comment: Dá pra resumir muita coisa desse processo em menos linhas.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Na verdade eu posso eliminar toda a validação, pois o form será só para mim, e o principal problema no momento é o insert dos multiplos valores. Consegue me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O exeplo mais simples é primeiro transformar os checkboxs em um array, adicionando `[]`colchetes no atributo `name`, depois verifique se existe algum valor em `$_POST['genero']` caso exista faça um `implode()` para transforma o array em uma string delimitada por virgulas, após toda essa formatação chama sua rotina para gravar no banco, fiz um simulação bem simples do que seria.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    1<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>
    2<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="2" /><br>
    3<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="3" /><br>
    4<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="4" /><br>
    5<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="5" /><br>
    6<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="6" /><br>
    7<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="7" /><br>
    8<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="8" />
    <input name="" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['genero']) && count($_POST['genero']) ){
    $itens = implode(',', $_POST['genero']);

    //sql simulada
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (id, nome, descricao, itens) VALUES (1, 'nome valor', 'descricao valor', '$itens')";
    echo $sql;
}

?>
```

Saída é algo parecido como

```
INSERT INTO tabela (id, nome, descricao, itens) VALUES (1, 'nome valor', 'descricao valor', '1,2,5')
```

Comment: Duvida: como possuo diversos campos na tabela, é possivel resumir chamando pela array? Coloquei o ultimo código ali em cima. Desde já obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Senhores! Muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram aqui. Consegui aprender mais um pouco sobre esta linguagem :) .

Segue solução:
Inclui a função do implode direto nos levantamentos de varias da array $form['genero'].

```
            $form['genero'] = implode(',', $_POST['genero']);           

            elseif (empty($_POST['genero']) && count($_POST['genero']) <= 5 )
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Preencha o gênero.</div>';
```

Deixo um MUITO obrigado a todos vcs, e vejo que as dicas que todos deram se enquadrava na solução, eu só não estava entendo, onde fazer a integração do implode.

Comment: Isso funciona para o meu caso ?http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178382/armazenar-m%C3%BAltiplos-select-numa-coluna-s%C3%B3-com-php-javascript-mysql

Answer (score -1):

Tente executar este código e veja que o resultado é exatamente o que você deseja, colocar os resultados de vários `checkbox` em um único campo no banco de dados, ou seja, colocar os resultados de vários `checkbox` em uma única `string`.

```html
   <form action="" method="POST">
<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="2"  />
<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="3" checked="checked" />
<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="4"  />
<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="5" checked="checked" />
<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="6"  />
<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="7" checked="checked" />
<input name="genero[]" type="checkbox" value="8" />
<input name="" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

código PHP:

```
<?php 


$r1 = "";
$valor = "";
$camposSelecionados= "";
$form = array();
if (isset($_POST['genero'])){
$form =  $_POST['genero'];

    foreach($form as $valor){
        if (!empty($valor)){
            $camposSelecionados .= ",$valor";
        }
    }
 if (strlen($camposSelecionados)>0){
    $camposSelecionados = substr($camposSelecionados,1,strlen($camposSelecionados));    
 }
 $r1 = implode(",", $form);
}

echo "Selecionados: $camposSelecionados<br>";
echo "Todos os checkbox: $r1"; 

    ?>
```

Comment: Colocar um `@` para ignorar erro não á uma forma adequada de se resolver o problema. Isso se chama gambiarra.

Comment: @IvanFerrer a duvida real é como integrar o implode junto a validação do campo genero.

Comment: O implode tem que ser no método `$_POST['genero']`; e depois você armazena no seu array de chave genero se precisar.

Comment: Selecionados: 1,2
Todos os checkbox: 1,2You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1 ) VALUES ( '1', '2' )' at line 1

Comment: Pelo entendi `$form` tem o nomes dos campos da tabela (ver `foreach`) ... porém parece que eles são números ai gera esse erro de sintaxe. @HenriqueSilva

Comment: Fiz algumas edições, @IvanFerrer foi mal usei o @ apenas para testar, esqueci de remover e colocar a validação correta da variável, mas já corrigi. HenriqueSilva, por favor, substitua a variável  $form['genero'] por $form no seu código.

Comment: @MaiconHerverton Você chegou a verificar a ultima atualização que fiz so problema?

Comment: Sim, o carinha aí pegou o meu código e otimizou ao seu problema. Que bom que resolveu @HenriqueSilva.